# Difference between defining queries in the repository interface or entity class?

Tags: jpa, repository, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, named-query

Sorry if this is a very nooby/stupid question, but I was wondering if there was any difference, besides implementation, between defining a query in the repository:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository<Employee, Integer> {

    @Query("select e from Employee e where e.name like :name")
    public List<Employee> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

and defining a query in the entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Employee.findByName", query="select e from Employee e where e.name like :name")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    //...
}
```

Like are there advantages/disadvantages to either one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking we recommend defining the queries at the repository interface for a very simple reason: it's conceptually closer to the query execution. Also, `@Query` has a few advanced options when it comes to the additional queries that e.g. need to be triggered to implement pagination.

However, if you want to re-use the query definition on multiple query methods, using a named query is still a reasonable option.

The most important aspect IMO is consistency either among the team or at least per repo. If you start with named queries, don't mix them up with `@Query` definitions as that might confuse developers or at least make it harder to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Oliver for the response!  If you get a chance, could you also take a look at one of my other questions about spring data jpa's paging to confirm the answer I selected? thanks lol [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008472/pagination-in-spring-data-jpa-limit-and-offset)