# How to query data via Spring data JPA with user defined offset and limit (Range)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Is it possible to fetch data in user defined ranges [int starting record -int last record]?

In my case **user will define** in query String in which **range** he wants to fetch data. 
I have tried something like this

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 10);
    Page<Project> list = projectRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);
```

Where spec is my defined specification but unfortunately this do not help.
May be I am doing something wrong here.

I have seen other spring jpa provided methods but nothing are of much help.

**user can enter something like this localhost:8080/Section/employee? range{"columnName":name,"from":6,"to":20}**

So this says to fetch employee data and it will fetch the first 15 records (sorted by columnName ) does not matter as of now.

If you can suggest me something better that would be great.if you think I have not provided enough information please let me know, I will provide required information.

**Update** :I do not want to use native or Create query statements (until I don't have any other option).
May be something like this:

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 10);
        Page<Project> list = projectRepository.findAll(spec, new pageable(int startIndex,int endIndex){
// here my logic.

});
```

If you have better options, you can suggest me that as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your approach didn't work, because `new PageRequest(0, 10);` doens't do what you think. As stated in [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#PageRequest-int-int-), the input arguments are `page` and `size`, not limit and offset.

As far as I know (and somebody correct me if I'm wrong), there is no "out of the box" support for what you need in default SrpingData repositories. But you can create custom implementation of `Pagable`, that will take limit/offset parameters. Here is basic example - [Spring data Pageable and LIMIT/OFFSET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217552/spring-data-pageable-and-limit-offset/30219294#30219294)

Comment: thanks for your answer,it has definately given me direction.

Answer (score 4):

**We can do this with Pagination and by setting the database table column name, value & row counts as below:**

```
 @Transactional(readOnly=true)
 public List<String> queryEmployeeDetails(String columnName,String columnData, int startRecord, int endRecord) {
    Query query =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(" from Employee emp where emp.col= :"+columnName);
    query.setParameter(columnName, columnData);
    query.setFirstResult(startRecord);
    query.setMaxResults(endRecord);
    List<String> list = (List<String>)query.list();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... can you illustrate me , how can we achieve this with Pagination ?

Comment: I believe you are trying to write `from Employee emp where emp.' + columnName + '= :foo'` and then `query.setParameter("foo", columnData);` ?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you want your repository to allow user to

1. Provide criteria for query (through `Specification`)
2. Provide column to sort
3. Provide the range of result to retrieve.

If my understanding is correctly, then:

In order to achieve 1., you can make use of `JpaSpecificationExecutor` from Spring Data JPA, which allow you to pass in `Specificiation` for query.

Both 2 and 3 is achievable in `JpaSpecificationExecutor` by use of `Pagable`.  `Pageable` allow you to provide the starting index, number of record, and sorting columns for your query.  You will need to implement your range-based `Pageable`.  `PageRequest` is a good reference on what you can implement (or you can extend it I believe).

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you please redirect me to some example,which shows the use of JpaSpecificationExecutor ? unfortunately i didnt find any.

Comment: Haven't used that actually.  Here is what I found by google: http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/  Although they are using QueryDSL for spec construction, I believe you can do it by some more hand-crafted way (QueryDSL requires code generation which may be a concern for you).  At least the page give you idea on how to work with `JpaSpecificationExecutor `

Comment: Actually I missed that `Pageable` is also providing `Sort`.  Hence, a custom `Pageable` (or using `PageRequest`) will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

So i got this working as one of the answer suggested ,i implemented my own Pageable and overrided **getPagesize()**,**getOffset()**,**getSort()** thats it.(In my case i did not need more)

```
public Range(int startIndex, int endIndex, String sortBy) {
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex = endIndex;
        this.sortBy = sortBy;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPageSize() {
        if (endIndex == 0)
            return 0;
        return endIndex - startIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOffset() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return startIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public Sort getSort() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (sortBy != null && !sortBy.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            return new Sort(Direction.ASC, sortBy);
        else
            return new Sort(Direction.ASC, "id");
    }
```

where **startIndex** ,**endIndex** are starting and last index of record.

to access it :

`repository.findAll(spec,new Range(0,20,"id");`

Answer (score 0):

There is no offset parameter you can simply pass. However there is a very simple solution for this:

```
int pageNumber = Math.floor(offset / limit) + ( offset % limit );
PageRequest pReq = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, limit);
```

The client just have to keep track on the offset instead of page number. By this I mean your controller would receive the offset instead of the page number.

Hope this helps!