# How to pass limit and off set values dynamically in native query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink, nativequery

I'm using native query to fetch the pagination results from PostgreSQL and I used this query and I'm getting the below exception:

```sql
SELECT a.*
  FROM table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.clmn1 = b.clmn1
  WHERE (a.clmn3 = ?3 OR a.clmn4 ISNULL)
  ORDER BY a.clmn1 DESC offset = ?1 limit = ?2
```

Query:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="select a.* from table1 a left outer join table2 b ON a.clmn1 = b.clmn1 where (a.clmn3= ?3 OR a.clmn4 isnull) order by a.clmn1 desc offset = ?1 limit = ?2")
public List<Result> getResults(int offset, int limit, int value);
```

Exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "="
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You are missing a space between is and null..

Comment: nope same issue

Comment: Restructured query above to point out the lack of space between "is" and "null"... `OR a.clmn4 ISNULL`

Comment: Maybe duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008472/pagination-in-spring-data-jpa-limit-and-offset

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your query. Remove the `=` and prefer named parameters like:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT a.* FROM table1 a "
    + " LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b"
    + " ON a.clmn1 = b.clmn1 "
    + " WHERE (a.clmn3= ?3 OR a.clmn4 IS NULL) "
    + " ORDER BY a.clmn1 DESC OFFSET :offset LIMIT :limit ")
public List<Result> getResults(@Param("offset")int offset, 
                               @Param("limit")int limit, int value);
```

***Disclaimer**: did not test how the param injection works but the syntax should be like this*

Answer (score 0):

I Believe the error is

```
offset = ?1 limit = ?2
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/queries-limit.html

No '=' is required on offset and limit