# JPA sorting query result after querying with Pageable

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I am having an @Entity like this:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable;

@Entity
@Data@NoArgsConstructor@AllArgsConstructor
public class Message extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private LocalDateTime messageDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    private String message;

}
```

And a repository like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
    //List<Message> findAllByOrderByMessageDateAsc(Pageable pageable);
    // With this I am trying to re-sort what I get

}
```

And a @Controller

```
@GetMapping("/messages")
    public String list(Model model) {
        Pageable limit = PageRequest.of(0, 5, Sort.by("messageDate").descending());
        model.addAttribute("messages", messageRepository.findAll(limit));
        //model.addAttribute("messages", messageRepository.findAllByOrderByMessageDateAsc(limit));
        return "messages";
    }
```

I get five latest messages in descending order. But how do I get them in ascending order?

Comment: Use Sort.by("messageDate").ascending()

Comment: If I instead of PageRequest.of(0, 5, Sort.by("messageDate").descending()) use PageRequest.of(0, 5, Sort.by("messageDate").ascending()) I get oldest five messages. I want latest five in ascending order.

Comment: What you need is last 5 message asc by massage date. The easiest way is do a count query then request again or you have to manually sort after fetching

Comment: I have tried 
long count = messageRepository.count();
Pageable limit = PageRequest.of((int)count/5, 5, Sort.by("messageDate").ascending());
It does not give five records all the time.
How do I sort after fetching?

Comment: I added an answer hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the last 5 messages in ascending order by massage date.
Two ways to solve it.

**Using Custom implementation of `Pageable`**

You can't use offset properly for `PageRequest`. So,
you need to use a custom implementation of `Pageable` for offset.
You can use custom implementation [OffsetBasedPageRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36365522/4207306). Then use it this way.

```
int totalCount = (int)serviceRepository.count();
Pageable pageable = new OffsetBasedPageRequest(totalCount - limit, limit, Sort.by("messageDate"));
messageRepository.findAll(pageable);
```

**After fetching Sort Page data**

You can get the list from `Page<T>` using `page.getContent()` then sort manually the list.

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, limit, Sort.by("messageDate").descending());
List<Message> list = messageRepository.findAll(pageable ).getContent();
List<Message> sorted =list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(r -> r.getMessageDate())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then again you have to create `Page<Massage>` if you want.

Comment: Thanks. That did not quite work. Error on this list.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getMessageDate())); But this worked List<Message> content = messageRepository.findAll(limit).getContent()
                .stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(r -> r.getMessageDate())).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Updated as you want

Comment: Maybe because list is immutable neither list.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getMessageDate()));  should work