# @Query annotation to filter the data

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am facing issue in this below statement

```
`SELECT b
FROM com.development.searchbooks.dto.BooksEntity b
WHERE lower(b.title) LIKE ?1
    OR lower(b.author_name) LIKE ?1
    OR lower(b.publication) LIKE ?1
ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?2`
```

unexpected token: LIMIT near line 1, column 173

This is the query i am using to filter based on keyword and order by ascending and doing pagination. i am getting error right after adding *"LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?2"* this POC.

Kindly help on this.

Comment: Are you passing correct values to `?2` ? How you are calling above SQL statement. can you check which SQL its firing in database from log?

Comment: check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/48651391/11745755

Comment: yes passing offset value for the initial time is 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIMIT keyword is not considered by jpa/jpql.
So for using LIMIT with @Query, we cam make native query flag true.

```
( using - nativeQuery=true )
```

Below is the example

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Table s ORDER BY s.id DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finalized Answer for my Question,

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE lower(title) LIKE %?1% OR lower(author_name) LIKE %?1% OR lower(publication) LIKE %?1% ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?2", nativeQuery = true)
```