# Java 11 - Springboot JPA - Pagination with Offset

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, offset, criteria, pageable

In my springboot 2.7.14 project I need to execute a query with a projection, specification and pagination.
I already tried the library "specification-with-projection" but it doesn't seem to fit my case because the query is still retrieving all the columns and only after that is mapping my projection.
So I ended up using a CriteriaQuery.
The front-end pass to the backend the query parameters, pageNumber (in base 1), pageSize and the offset.
How can I put all these information together for the execution of the query and the return of a Page object?
This is my instruction for the execution of the query:

```
List<MyDto> myDtoList= entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
                .setFirstResult(((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize) + offset)
                .setMaxResults(pageSize)
                .getResultList();
```

After this I do a Select Count to get the total and finally return all the information together with this instruction:

```
return new PageImpl<>(myDtoList, PageRequest.of(pageNumber - 1, pageSize), totalElements);
```

The Page object returned in this way not include the correct offset, but only the one from the operation pageNumber*pageSize.
I'm pretty sure the problem is in the implementation of PageRequest.of, so I found this class OffsetBasedPageRequest in this answer:
[Pagination in Spring Data JPA (limit and offset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008472/pagination-in-spring-data-jpa-limit-and-offset)
Unfortunately this specific solution seems to not work with the latest version of Springboot.
Has anyone tried to do this recently and can help me with a correct implementation of an OffsetBasedPageRequest please?